# How to find a point from where three vectors originate?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Okay so first of all I tried to make the title to sound like I understand something about mathematics, correct me if I am wrong with it.

Backstory / context:

I bumped into this problem when me and my friend were talking one night in discord about where my friend should order a pizza from. He then sent me a screenshot of the choices he had, but it was only showing two pizza places with distances to them, as each pizza place has some max delivery radius set. Suddenly a light went on in my head and I told my friend that if I he had sent me a third pizza place in the screenshot, I could find out where he lives based on the locations of the pizza places and the distances shown.

So then he sent me a picture of a third pizza place and I got to work. I have heard about triangulation before so I thought that it would be a good idea to read about how that works, but in the end I either did not understand the idea or the idea of triangulation is basically that I "kind of" know where I am, but I just don't know where that location is on the map, but since I had no idea about where this said friend lived, I came into conclusion that I don't have enough data for triangulation.

So the next thing I did was what felt like the second obvious one to me - I drew a circle around each pizza place with the distances as the circle's radiuses, probably because that is how they find people in CIA-style TV-shows. Well that did basically nothing, now I just had a VERY vague area where he might live aka. where all three circles overlap I guess.

So on I went to the third obvious thing, which was to draw a triangle through the pizza places. I then googled about [finding a triangle centroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html) and got pretty convincing results. I figured that since the centroid point is inside all of the three circles I drew - this has to be where my friend lives. I then sent an image of my solution to my friend ready to receive applauds.

Well my solution was completely wrong. Not even close. I understand that the distances to the pizza places were probably calculated via roads and not with straight lines, so that might give me some error, but the solution of mine was too far off to blame it on error.

Unfortunately I like my and my friend's privacy, so I am not going to post an image of the original problem, but instead I spend some time in photoshop and created a fake scenario:

[image: fake scenario]

- Distances are not actually meters, but pixel values photoshop gave me
- Green dot is the answer, or where my fake friend lives. This point is actually unknown.
- The pizzas are locations of fake pizzerias. These are known.
- The pink lines are the distances to the pizzerias as given by the website
- The cyan and the red lines, as well as the red midpoint dots and the blue centroid dot are parts of my solution or what I have tried to do to find the green point

So how can we find the green point (where my friend lives)? Can it even be found?

In mathematical terms, like said in the title, I guess this is a question about finding an originating point for three vectors of which lengths and directions we know.

(If someone finds a use for it, I can provide the .psd file of the map image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 3 pizza places have coordinates $$c_1 =(x_1,y_1), c_2 =(x_2,y_2), c_3=(x_3,y_3)$$ and distances to your friend's location $r_1, r_2, r_3$ respectively then your friend's location is at a point where the 3 circles defined by those centers and radii intersect. It is possible that the intersection set of 3 circles is empty, in which case the given distances/locations of the places are incorrectly given (or there's a small error in which case you should try to find an intersection with rings that serve as a circle with a 'thickness' $\epsilon$ to account for measurement error, another possibility being trying to find the closest point to all circles when the initial data is not entirely accurate). It is also possible that there are infinitely many such intersection points, when the 3 circles coincide - then your friend's place can be at any point on the circle. Finally it's possible that 2 circles coincide and the third intersects them at 2 locations. In this case your friend's place can be in any of these two locations. Notice how you get more than one solution only when you actually have less that 3 circles, since coinciding such give no extra information. Finally this problem is probably more interesting in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
In 3d for example 2 spheres would intersect (if they do not coincide and the intersection is not empty) such that you get a circle. A circle intersected with another sphere would yield (if it's not on the surface of the other sphere) 2 points. Finally you'll need another sphere to bring it down to one point. By a similar logic I assume that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you will need $n+1$ hyperspheres in the general case. Note that in degenerate cases you will get more than one solution (possible infinitely many). Additionally if you have extra constraints, such as your friend's place and two pizza places lying on a line you need only 2 circles (in $n$ dimensions 2 hyperspheres also). So in the general case you need $n+1$ circles, but it is entirely possible that less are enough in special cases (the minimum being 2, imagine 2 spheres touching at a single point).
This problem would be even more interesting on manifolds where the geodesic distance is used for example.

Comment: I feel dumb now. I just tried the circle method again with the fake example I made and in that case the circles intersect pretty much perfectly at the point of the house. I guess I had large errors with the real pizza place coordinates and distances, plus two of the real pizza places were nearly in the same direction which resulted in weird overlapping circles. Now I am wondering if probabilities can somehow be applied in some of the cases you were talking about, where there were more than 1 solution. Isn't the probability of the house location higher in sections where 2 circles overlap?

Comment: Thank you by the way! I also forgot the very powerful method of simplifying problems when I was trying to figure this out. Should have thought about it with the line and two points like you said and then adapted it to two dimensions.

Comment: @Piwwoli Depends on the assumptions regarding the error of your measurements. In case you know the error's probability distribution you can try to predict the 'better' location, that's not as trivial though. I would just go with finding a point that's closest to all 3 circles in case they do not intersect, or the method with using rings rather than circles and then taking the point that's farthest from all edges in the intersection region.

Comment: By a ring I mean the region enclosed between the circles with radii $r+\epsilon$ and $r-\epsilon$ and the same center, where $\epsilon \in [0,r]$ is some relatively small value to account for the measurement error. Note that you can pick two different values $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ for the plus and minus, but all of this boils down to the assumptions you make about the error.

Comment: Here's something for extra insight. When you say that point $X$ is at a distance (euclidean distance) $r$ from point $C$, where you know $r$ and $C$, then $X$ lies on the hypersphere with center $C$ and radius $r$. That is, the set of all points at a distance $r$ from $C$ forms a hypersphere (in 2d a circle). When you have a constraint such that a point is in two sets at the same time, that means that it is in their intersection. That's why when you ask for a point that's at distances $r_1, r_2, r_3$ away from points $C_1, C_2, C_3$ respectively...

Comment: ...you get that it is in the intersection of the 3 circles. Note that for other norms, the set of equidistant points to some other is not in general a hypersphere (this holds for the euclidean distance though which is what people refer to usually in everyday life). A good example of a different norm would be the taxicab norm (you can read up on the internet why it is called so, it's pretty intuitive). Back to my original point - the idea of reducing a seemingly complex problem to simply an intersection of sets (if possible) is very powerful and you can solve a multitude of problems with it.

Comment: Sorry I had to take my time to visualize what you said. Got a huge interest in math but after years I still lag a minute with every relatively uncommon character and the general syntax used. But yeah, it makes sense if you can't get an exact intersection point, then you could try to find a smaller region instead by giving the circles some slack! I was wondering why you were talking about farthest point from edges and not a middle point, but I was incorrectly thinking about the region as a simple rectangle at first.

Comment: Since you are talking about this in terms of sets of (possible) points and what I would call "filtering" some points out with some criteria such as the three distances - are there any other interesting, more powerful or even unintuitive "filtering criterias" that could be used specifically in this case? (I'm a programmer at heart, thus the vocabulary differences and I am always looking for clever or sometimes even outright "stupid but it works" ways to do things in different ways)

Comment: Ooh! Taxicab geometry is really interesting, mainly because I have been thinking about real life in terms of computers a lot. Like you were to draw a line at an angle on a computer screen, it is technically not straight, but jagged like that. So I've been thinking if anything in real life is really actually straight at all either or is it just a matter of resolution and scale or something.

Comment: As long as you can formulate your problem so that you have a feasibility set, that feasibility set may be constructed through whatever set operations you want (even infinite such). Usually this results in mathematical optimization problems. The thing with the jagged line is due to finite resolution and not enough samples in each pixel (you can technically make it look smooth by having grey colour rather than black and white), it's called aliasing and for example signal/image processing deals with this. For all intents and purposes at our scale a lot of things can be considered continuous.